# Has this 2006 experiment about the effect of distant intention on water been challenged?

Tags: water, masuru-emoto

While researching Masaru Emoto (who I hadn't heard of before today), I found plenty of places where his work was rejected as being only pseudo-scientific, yet I also found this one paper: [Double-Blind Test of the Effects of Distant Intention on Water Crystal Formation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1550830706003272). I didn't make a concerted and thorough effort to find a challenge, debunking, or supporting paper, but neither did I see any mention of this paper on another site that debunked Masaru's other work (and was put up after this paper was published). So I'm asking you guys if the results of this paper (or its methodology) were ever supported, challenged, or debunked.

---

I am aware of [this very related question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16781/does-masaru-emotos-experiment-show-human-consciousness-affects-the-aesthetics-o), but I don't think they're duplicates.

Comment: I understand you don't think they are duplicates, but I would argue they are because (a) that study was not an independent reproduction. Emoto was a co-author. (b) Rather than ask 'has anyone reproduced this study?', it would be better to ask about the claim the study makes... which brings us back to the original question.

Comment: You seem to have two questions here.1.